Steering wheel rotation
Is there a way to rotate the tires of a car model and have the steering wheel move with it correctly? I tried to copy the rotation of my tires on to my steering wheel and it rotated in the wrong direction. Does anyone know how I can fix this?
Here's a visual, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.



hello please share the wheel + steering wheel: https://blend-exchange.com/

I think a property driver is the way to go here. I'll leave it for someone else to do a detailed explanation.

you could also use the transformation constraint

@moonboots 

There's a very comprehensive tutorial on rigging a car just using constraints here with the section about the steering wheel here and rigging the wheel direction to follow a path just before it.

Is rotating in the wrong direction the only problem there, or do other things also fail?

You could use a Transformation constraint, in the Map From part choose the source object axis that you want to take into account, in the Map To part choose the axis on which you want your object to rotate and what is the source object axis:

Result (animated gif below). Note that your object are already off-axed, if this is what you want you'd better realign them with the global axis, parent them to empties and tilt the empties, in that case choose Local Space instead of World Space:


This worked! thank you so much!

Some background. The maximum angle a car's wheels will turn is somewhere around ± 45°. See 1 for a discussion.
The amount the steering wheel turns per degree of wheel turn is somewhere around 12:1 to 20:1 See 2. This means the steering wheel should turn about 3 to 5 times as the wheels turn from full left to full right.
To set this up as a Blender animation, I'll assume there is a "Front Wheel" object that turns on the X axis for steering. Similarly, the "Steering Wheel" object should rotate about its Y axis and it should be the child of another Empty that is rotated on the X axis for the steering wheel tilt.
We then create a Driver on the "Steering Wheel" Y rotation, using the "Front Wheel" object's X rotation as its variable, var, and the formula would be 12*var. The constant "12" is from the steering ratio 2 and could vary between 12 and 20. The smaller number would be most appropriate for a race car and the larger number for a truck, but feel free to adjust for artistic merit.

